# Macro won't parse the expression the same recursively

Tags: rust

I'm creating a recursive Rust macro that can extract a bang `!` from the beginning of an expression.

I can do that just fine like this

```
macro_rules! test {
    (!$e:expr) => {
        println!(stringify!($e));
    };
}

fn main() {
    test!(!'a'); //Outputs: 'a'
}
```

But has soon as I try to call it from within the macro itself, it no longer works and I get complier errors.

```
macro_rules! test {
    (@process, !$e:expr) => {
        println!(stringify!($e));
    };

    ($e:expr) => {
        test!(@process, $e);
    };
}

fn main() {
    test!(!'a');
}
```

```
no rules expected the token `!'a'`
```

I don't think this is a typo because I can directly call it without issue on the second example. Is Rust caching the expression and then not reevaluating it? Can I somehow force Rust to reevaluate it, or is something else happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `!'a'` gets parsed as an expression `$e`, and when `$e` is passed through, it's passed as a whole expression, no longer as a token sequence (so the latter macro invocation will not see `!`). You can work around this by capturing it as a raw token sequence instead:

```
macro_rules! test {
    (@process, !$e:expr) => {
        println!(stringify!($e));
    };

    ($($e:tt)*) => {
        test!(@process, $($e)*);
    };
}
```